# How to choose minimum value row in Group By sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's a closely resembling sqlite database that I'm working with -

```
CREATE TABLE sampleData(
   pincode INTEGER NOT NULL,
   place_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   price INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE(pincode, place_id)
);
```

I was looking to find names of places in every pincode(only 1 place per pincode) which has the lowest price there. The simplest query I could come up with -

```
SELECT * FROM sampleData 
WHERE price > 0
GROUP BY pincode
ORDER BY PRICE
```

which seems to work in sqlite(?) but fails to work in pg9.6 and gives wrong result in Mysql. Here's another one which seems to give same result -

```
SELECT * FROM sampleData 
WHERE price > 0
GROUP BY pincode
HAVING MIN(PRICE)
```

which has similar results as last one. I was wondering what's wrong with these queries and would love some help crafting the correct one.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d8705/2)

Answer (score 4):

Your first query is malformed SQL.  `SELECT *` doesn't make sense with `GROUP BY`.  It so happens that SQLite extends the SQL language to do what you want.  I consider that a bad thing.

In any case, you can do:

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM sampleData sd
WHERE sd.price = (SELECT MIN(sd2.price)
                  FROM sampleData sd2
                  WHERE sd2.price > 0 AND
                        sd2.pincode = sd.pincode
                 );
```

This can return duplicate rows, if multiple places have the same price.  Assuming `place_id` is unique, you can revise this to:

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM sampleData sd
WHERE sd.place_id = (SELECT sd2.place_id
                     FROM sampleData sd2
                     WHERE sd2.price > 0 AND
                           sd2.pincode = sd.pincode
                     ORDER BY sd2.price ASC
                     LIMIT 1
                    );
```

Comment: Isn't the second one prone to "subquery returns more than one row" errors? Did you forget a limit?

Comment: the combination of pincode and place_id is unique - `UNIQUE(pincode, place_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT pincode,place,name,MIN(PRICE)
FROM sampleData 
WHERE price > 0
GROUP BY pincode,place,name
```

Comment: @nubprogrammer: Not if you use it as posted by mkRabbani, that is using `pincode` **not** `*`.

Comment: You can simply add other fields in selection and group by part. This will work.

Comment: Edited the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need a query to get the min `price` for each `pincode` and then join it to the table:

```
select s.* 
from sampledata s inner join (
  select pincode, min(price) price
  from sampledata
  group by pincode
) g on g.pincode = s.pincode and g.price = s.price
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tKPeaNqA3YXQwd6R1E8M9r/0).
Results:

```
| pincode | place_id | price | name   |
| ------- | -------- | ----- | ------ |
| 123     | 2        | 13    | Place2 |
| 222     | 18       | 21    | Place5 |
| 456     | 5        | 200   | Place3 |
```

Comment: this breaks 1 place per pincode if prices are similar

Comment: This will return more than 1 places for a pincode if all have equal min price.